# Acting on a sortedlist before it's passed to a tableview?

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have a TableView backed by sorted and filtered lists in the usual fashion:

```
FilteredList<Filedata> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(eeModel.data, p -> true);
SortedList<Filedata> sortedList = new SortedList<>(filteredData);
table.setItems(sortedList);
sortedList.comparatorProperty().bind(table.comparatorProperty());
```

I need to be able to set the background colors on cell items which match their neighbours.  I've tried doing this in the appropriate table cell factory method and whilst it works fine to start with it breaks down as the table is scrolled as the cell factory is called in an unpredictable order.

I'm guessing the best way might be to work on the sortedList each time it gets resorted, or do I need to interpose another list between the tableview and the sortedlist in order to do this?

Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

UPDATE:

As per James_D's request, this is the current cell factory:

```
        filename.setCellFactory(column -> {
        return new TableCell<Filedata, String>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                if (item == null || empty) {
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    setText(item);

                    int index = this.getTableRow().getIndex();
                    String prevCell = filename.getCellData(index-1);
                    String nextCell = filename.getCellData(index+1);

                    final boolean nextCellEqual = nextCell != null && nextCell.equals(item);
                    final boolean prevCellEqual = prevCell != null && prevCell.equals(item);

                    if ( prevCellEqual ) {
                        setStyle( RowColour.getColour() );                          
                        System.out.println( "prevCellEqual " + index + " set to " + RowColour.getColour() );
                    }
                    else if ( nextCellEqual ) {
                        RowColour.nextColour();
                        setStyle( RowColour.getColour() );  
                        System.out.println( "nextCellEqual " + index + " set to " + RowColour.getColour() );
                    }
                    else {
                        setStyle("");
                    }

                }
            }
        };
    });
```

where RowColour is a simple static class that records the current color in use and switches it on request.  Obviously that's calling order dependant.  But even if I eliminated that I think I could still end up painting non-matching cells the same color without having a global overview.

UPDATE - sortedList/ListChangeListener possibility

```
        sortedList.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Change<?> change) {
            System.out.println("SortedList size: " + sortedList.size());

            String thisFilename;
            String prevFilename;
            String nextFilename;

            final int size = sortedList.size();
            dupeFlags = new int[size];
            int colour = 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { 
                thisFilename = sortedList.get(i).getFilename();

                if (i > 0) {
                    prevFilename = sortedList.get(i-1).getFilename();   
                }
                else {
                    prevFilename = null;
                }

                if (i < size-1) {
                    nextFilename = sortedList.get(i+1).getFilename();   
                }
                else {
                    nextFilename = null;
                }

                final boolean nextEqual = nextFilename != null && nextFilename.equals(thisFilename);
                final boolean prevEqual = prevFilename != null && prevFilename.equals(thisFilename);

                if ( prevEqual ) {
                    dupeFlags[i] = colour;
                    System.out.println( "pe " + i + " coloured: " + colour );
                }
                else if ( nextEqual ) {
                    colour = 3 - colour;
                    dupeFlags[i] = colour;
                    System.out.println( "ne " + i + " coloured: " + colour );
                }
                else {
                    dupeFlags[i] = 0;
                    System.out.println( "-- " + i + " coloured: " + 0 );
                }                                       
            }
        }

    });



        filename.setCellFactory(column -> {
        return new TableCell<Filedata, String>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                if (item == null || empty) {
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    setText(item);

                    int index = this.getTableRow().getIndex();                      

                    switch (dupeFlags[index]) {
                        case 0:
                             setStyle("");
                             break;

                        case 1: 
                             setStyle( "-fx-background-color: yellow" );
                             break;

                        case 2:
                             setStyle("-fx-background-color: red" );
                             break;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: Using a cell factory is probably the appropriate method. You just need to code it without any assumptions about when the cells are created and updated. Can you post a simplified version of what you tried?

Comment: don't put logic into the cell - that's just as wrong as it was in Swing's renderers. Instead, have an external controller that updates itself as needed and let the cell check into the controller @James_D

Comment: The only logic I'm suggesting putting into the cell is to determine the style based on the state of the item it's displaying. See the sample code below: the cell just observes the state of the item and changes its style (pseudoclass state) accordingly. (I.e. the view is observing the model.)

Answer (score 0):

As you mention, the problem here is one of the order in which things are called. You also may have to deal with the possibility that the index changes but the item doesn't (probably unlikely, but certainly possible). In that case your code won't get invoked at all.

This is (kind of) an example of the more general principle that subclassing (`TableCell` in this case) breaks encapsulation, because you need to know details about the superclass' implementation (in this case, whether the index is updated before the item, or vice-versa).

**Update**

This is a bit harder than I first thought. The cell, of course, also needs to update when the value in one of the adjacent cells changes. Since the cells that are adjacent to the current cell may change (by filtering, sorting, or even just scrolling), the listener on those values needs to be moved to the correct item when that happens.

So the approach I have taken here is to use a fairly minimal subclass of `TableCell` that registers a listener with its `item` and `index` properties. It also wraps the item properties of each of the adjacent cells in an object property, and updates those when the index changes. I **think** this does the job; I'm confident the approach is right but you may need to think it through and make sure you are covering all possibilities.

I just used a css pseudoclass for the cell color, which is faster (I am told) than manipulating css classes and much faster than manipulating the inline style. The css file is just

highlight-matching-cells.css:

```
.table-cell:highlight {
    -fx-background-color: salmon ;
}
```

And the example is

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.SortedList;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class HighlightMatchingCells extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Item> table = new TableView<>();
        ObservableList<Item> data = createData();
        FilteredList<Item> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(data, item -> true);
        SortedList<Item> sortedList = new SortedList<>(filteredData);
        sortedList.comparatorProperty().bind(table.comparatorProperty());
        table.setItems(sortedList);

        TableColumn<Item, String> nameCol = makeCol(String.class, "Name", Item::nameProperty);
        TableColumn<Item, Number> value1Col = makeCol(Number.class, "Value 1", Item::value1Property);
        TableColumn<Item, Number> value2Col = makeCol(Number.class, "Value 2", Item::value2Property);
        TableColumn<Item, Number> value3Col = makeCol(Number.class, "Value 3", Item::value3Property);
        TableColumn<Item, Number> totalCol = makeCol(Number.class, "Total", Item::totalProperty);

        table.getColumns().addAll(Arrays.asList(nameCol, value1Col, value2Col, value3Col, totalCol));

        Callback<TableColumn<Item, Number>, TableCell<Item, Number>> cellFactory = 
                col -> new MatchingAdjacentCell();

        value1Col.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
        value2Col.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
        value3Col.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
        totalCol.setCellFactory(cellFactory);

        Node controls = makeControls(filteredData);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table, controls, null, null, null);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("highlight-matching-cells.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    private ObservableList<Item> createData() {
        ObservableList<Item> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        final Random rng = new Random();
        for (int i=1; i<=100; i++) {
            int value1 = rng.nextInt(10)+1;
            int value2 = rng.nextInt(10)+1;
            int value3 = rng.nextInt(10)+1;
            String name = "Item "+i;
            data.add(new Item(name, value1, value2, value3));
        }
        return data;
    }

    private HBox makeControls(FilteredList<Item> filteredData) {
        TextField filterTextField = new TextField("30");
        CheckBox filterCheckBox = new CheckBox("Filter");
        Button updateFilterButton = new Button("Update Filter");
        updateFilterButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            if (filterCheckBox.isSelected()) {
                int maxTotal = 30 ;
                try {
                    maxTotal = Integer.parseInt(filterTextField.getText());
                } catch (NumberFormatException exc) {
                    filterTextField.setText("30");
                }
                int max = maxTotal ;
                filteredData.setPredicate(item -> item.getTotal() <= max);
            } else {
                filteredData.setPredicate(item -> true) ;
            }
        });

        HBox controls = new HBox(5, filterTextField, filterCheckBox, updateFilterButton);
        controls.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        controls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        return controls;
    }


    private <T> TableColumn<Item, T> makeCol(Class<T> type, String title, Function<Item, ObservableValue<T>> valueMapper) {
        TableColumn<Item, T> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> valueMapper.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        return col ;
    }

    public static class MatchingAdjacentCell extends TableCell<Item, Number> {

        private final ObjectProperty<ObservableValue<Number>> previousItem = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(); ;
        private final ObjectProperty<ObservableValue<Number>> nextItem = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

        public MatchingAdjacentCell() {
            itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> updateCell());
            indexProperty().addListener((obs, oldIndex, newIndex) -> updateCell());

            // update when adjacent cells change value:
            ChangeListener<Number> adjacentItemValueUpdateListener = (obs, oldValue, newValue) -> updateCell();

            // register/de-register this listener when adjacent cells change:
            ChangeListener<ObservableValue<Number>> adjacentItemListener = (obs, oldObservable, newObservable) -> {
                if (oldObservable != null) {
                    oldObservable.removeListener(adjacentItemValueUpdateListener);
                }
                if (newObservable != null) {
                    newObservable.addListener(adjacentItemValueUpdateListener);
                }
            };

            previousItem.addListener(adjacentItemListener);
            nextItem.addListener(adjacentItemListener);
        }

        private void updateCell() {
            final PseudoClass highlightClass = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("highlight");
            int index = getIndex();

            if (index < 0 || index >= getTableView().getItems().size()) {
                pseudoClassStateChanged(highlightClass, false);
                setText(null);
                previousItem.set(null);
                nextItem.set(null);
            } else {
                boolean highlight = false ;
                if (getItem() == null) {
                    setText("");
                } else {
                    int cellValue = getItem().intValue();
                    setText(Integer.toString(cellValue));
                    if (index > 0) {
                        ObservableValue<Number> previous = getTableColumn().getCellObservableValue(index - 1);
                        previousItem.set(previous);
                        int previousCellValue = previous.getValue().intValue();
                        if (previousCellValue == cellValue) {
                            highlight = true ;
                        }
                    }
                    if (index < getTableView().getItems().size()-1 && (! highlight)) {
                        ObservableValue<Number> next = getTableColumn().getCellObservableValue(index + 1);
                        nextItem.set(next);
                        int nextCellValue = next.getValue().intValue();
                        if (nextCellValue == cellValue) {
                            highlight = true ;
                        }
                    }
                    pseudoClassStateChanged(highlightClass, highlight);
                }
            }
        }


    }

    public static class Item implements Comparable<Item> {
        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name", "");
        private final IntegerProperty value1 = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "value1", 0);
        private final IntegerProperty value2 = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "value1", 0);
        private final IntegerProperty value3 = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "value1", 0);

        private final ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper total = new ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper(this, "total", 0);

        public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return this.name;
        }
        public final java.lang.String getName() {
            return this.nameProperty().get();
        }
        public final void setName(final java.lang.String name) {
            this.nameProperty().set(name);
        }
        public final IntegerProperty value1Property() {
            return this.value1;
        }
        public final int getValue1() {
            return this.value1Property().get();
        }
        public final void setValue1(final int value1) {
            this.value1Property().set(value1);
        }
        public final IntegerProperty value2Property() {
            return this.value2;
        }
        public final int getValue2() {
            return this.value2Property().get();
        }
        public final void setValue2(final int value2) {
            this.value2Property().set(value2);
        }
        public final IntegerProperty value3Property() {
            return this.value3;
        }
        public final int getValue3() {
            return this.value3Property().get();
        }
        public final void setValue3(final int value3) {
            this.value3Property().set(value3);
        }
        public final javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerProperty totalProperty() {
            return this.total.getReadOnlyProperty();
        }
        public final int getTotal() {
            return this.totalProperty().get();
        }        


        public Item(String name, int value1, int value2, int value3) {

            total.bind(Bindings.createIntegerBinding(() -> getValue1() + getValue2() + getValue3(), 
                    this.value1, this.value2, this.value3));

            this.setName(name);
            this.setValue1(value1);
            this.setValue2(value2);
            this.setValue3(value3);
        }
        @Override
        public int compareTo(Item o) {
            return Integer.compare(getTotal(), o.getTotal());
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is going to quite work as runs of duplicate values which border each other are going to be painted with the same color.

Your comment about breaking encapsulation is, I think, a critical one.  I'm not sure guaranteeing lack of clashes can be solved (easily) at the TableCell level. I'm considering instead putting a ListChangeListener on the SortedList to run the list and build a list of duplicates which the TableCell factory can just pick up and apply.

(cont...)

Comment: (...)

I'm given pause though about "the possibility that the index changes but the item doesn't".  I'm not sure what this means.  Does it imply that I'm going to find it non-trivial to match the item in the table cell back to the item I processed in the SortedList?

Comment: If an item is inserted into the table's list (i.e. in the data; this could happen if your filter changes, for example), then the index of items after the insertion changes. One possible implementation of `TableView` would be to keep the same cells for those items and insert a new (or unused) cell in the correct location. In that case, the cells below it would keep the same items, but change their indexes. I don't think it currently is implemented like that, but in future it could be. But I don't think it makes it hard to find the item in the list.

Comment: I've added some prototype code to the original post which contains a ListChangeListener.  It seems to work ok but depends on the item's TableRow index matching the index in the SortedList.  Is this a reasonable assumption or do I really need to put a listener on each cell?